# Add item back to for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I am working on some code, and I cannot figure out how to create the behavior that I want. I want to iterate through a list, and pull some data.  In my real code, the code is designed to pull some data, but the data is posted at different times and not really in a predictable fashion.  What I'd like to do is add the iterable back into the list if there is an error.

Example Code

```
my_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish']


for animal in my_list:
    try:
        get.('www.somerandomurl_{}.com'.format(animal))
        print("good work!")
    except:
        add item back to list, try again once the rest of the list is compete
```

Is there a way to do this?   Possibly even telling python to wait for n minutes to try again with the items that had an error

Comment: One of possible ways is to loop over indexes and increment index in `else` block after `except`. Another way is to put your `try .. except` into a `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop that will run until you've fetched all the items, at each run select (and pop) an element:

- if success: you're good
- if fail : put it back in the values to try

```
from requests import get
from collections import deque

my_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'fish']
to_fetch = deque(my_list)

while to_fetch:
    to_try = to_fetch.popleft()
    try:
        res = get('www.somerandomurl_{}.com'.format(to_try))
        print("good work!", res.text)
    except Exception:
        print("Failed", to_try, "but will try again later")
        to_fetch.append(to_try)
```

Comment: I would just use `x = to_fetch.popleft()` first, then `to_fetch.append(x)` in the event of an exception.

Comment: very cool!  And very straight forward.  I haven't used the collections library before.  Looks like there might be some other things in there worth exploring.